# Como actualizar Varchar SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema tengo muchos registros quisiera que se actualizen de:

```
+----------------------+---------+
|      Craftname       | userUID |
+----------------------+---------+
| 00000000000000000070 |    1    |
+----------------------+---------+
| 02020204042200000070 |    2    |
+----------------------+---------+
| 04040709001000000090 |    3    |
+----------------------+---------+
| 00000000000012000090 |    4    |
+----------------------+---------+
| 00000000000012000090 |    5    |
+----------------------+---------+
| 04040000003000000090 |    6    |
+----------------------+---------+
| 04040000008200000090 |    7    |
+----------------------+---------+
```

Intento usar este Script tipo asi:

```
IF (SELECT SUBSTRING(Craftname,1,2) FROM dateas.dbo.inventarios)= 04 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Craftname VARCHAR(20), 
@Str TINYINT,
@Dex TINYINT,
@Rec TINYINT,
@Int TINYINT,
@Wis TINYINT,
@Luc TINYINT,
@HP TINYINT,
@MP TINYINT,
@SP TINYINT
            SET @Craftname = (SELECT Craftname FROM dateas.dbo.inventarios)
            SET @Str = '08'
            SET @Dex = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,3,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @Rec = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,5,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @Int = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,7,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @Wis = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,9,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @Luc = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,11,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @HP = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,13,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @MP = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,15,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @SP = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,17,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @Enchant = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,19,2) AS TINYINT)
                UPDATE dateas.dbo.inventarios
                SET Craftname = @Str + @Dex + @Rec + @Int + @Wis + @Luc + @FinalHP + @MP + @SP + @Enchant
END
```

Para Obtener este resultado:

```
+----------------------+---------+
|      Craftname       | userUID |
+----------------------+---------+
| 00000000000000000070 |    1    |
+----------------------+---------+
| 02020208082200000070 |    2    |
+----------------------+---------+
| 08080709001000000090 |    3    |
+----------------------+---------+
| 00000000000012000090 |    4    |
+----------------------+---------+
| 00000000000012000090 |    5    |
+----------------------+---------+
| 08080000003000000090 |    6    |
+----------------------+---------+
| 08080000008200000090 |    7    |
+----------------------+---------+
```

NOTA: Lo importante que necesito es que se quiten los 04 de cada Craftname pero conserven cada digito por igual del resto y los que no contengan 04 adelante NO sean alterados ¿Que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Esto es un UPDATE bastante sencillo. Sin embargo, tienes código que da la impresión de que hay algo más que está pasando porque divides la cadena en muchas partes para después unirla.

Para reemplazar el `04` con `08` en cualquier parte de las cadenas, solo tienes que filtrar las cadenas afectadas con el `WHERE` y usar `REPLACE` para reemplazar los caracteres que deseas.

```
UPDATE inventarios SET
    Craftname = CONCAT(
                        IIF( SUBSTRING( Craftname, 1 , 2) = '04', '08', SUBSTRING( Craftname, 1 , 2)),
                        IIF( SUBSTRING( Craftname, 3 , 2) = '04', '08', SUBSTRING( Craftname, 3 , 2)),
                        IIF( SUBSTRING( Craftname, 5 , 2) = '04', '08', SUBSTRING( Craftname, 5 , 2)),
                        IIF( SUBSTRING( Craftname, 7 , 2) = '04', '08', SUBSTRING( Craftname, 7 , 2)),
                        IIF( SUBSTRING( Craftname, 9 , 2) = '04', '08', SUBSTRING( Craftname, 9 , 2)),
                        IIF( SUBSTRING( Craftname, 11, 2) = '04', '08', SUBSTRING( Craftname, 11, 2)),
                        IIF( SUBSTRING( Craftname, 13, 2) = '04', '08', SUBSTRING( Craftname, 13, 2)),
                        IIF( SUBSTRING( Craftname, 15, 2) = '04', '08', SUBSTRING( Craftname, 15, 2)),
                        IIF( SUBSTRING( Craftname, 17, 2) = '04', '08', SUBSTRING( Craftname, 17, 2)),
                        IIF( SUBSTRING( Craftname, 19, 2) = '04', '08', SUBSTRING( Craftname, 19, 2)))
WHERE Craftname LIKE '%04%';
```

Comment: Espera por like si me lo se lo que no se es el Where ejemplo 040400000000070 necesito asi mismo convertir todo lo que sea 04 este donde este este

Comment: Eso no es lo que indica tu pregunta o lo que muestran tus resultados de ejemplo o el código.

Comment: la editare entonces

Comment: Respuesta editada

Comment: no seria mejor asi por que es de grupos pares de 2 en 2 si edito un 04 puede tomarse en ese tipo como 40 ejemplo 00.00.40.00.00.04 en ese caso me quitara el 40 y pondra la sustitucion creo que el update seria mi respuesta abajo no?

Comment: En ningún lugar indicas que es por pares. ¿Entiendes por qué es importante especificar todos los detalles desde el inicio? Tu respuesta es ineficiente porque tiene que leer y modificar la tabla múltiples veces.

Answer (score 0):

No seria esta la respuesta mas logica ya que el craftname tiene 20 digitos y ocupo cambie los grupos pares 04 el resultado seria 80 o me equivoco?

```
UPDATE inventarios SET  Craftname = STUFF( Craftname,  1, 2, '80') WHERE Craftname = STUFF( Craftname,  1, 2, '04')
UPDATE inventarios SET  Craftname = STUFF( Craftname,  3, 2, '80') WHERE Craftname = STUFF( Craftname,  3, 2, '04')
UPDATE inventarios SET  Craftname = STUFF( Craftname,  5, 2, '80') WHERE Craftname = STUFF( Craftname,  5, 2, '04')
UPDATE inventarios SET  Craftname = STUFF( Craftname,  7, 2, '80') WHERE Craftname = STUFF( Craftname,  7, 2, '04')
UPDATE inventarios SET  Craftname = STUFF( Craftname,  9, 2, '80') WHERE Craftname = STUFF( Craftname,  9, 2, '04')
UPDATE inventarios SET  Craftname = STUFF( Craftname, 11, 2, '80') WHERE Craftname = STUFF( Craftname, 11, 2, '04')
UPDATE inventarios SET  Craftname = STUFF( Craftname, 13, 2, '80') WHERE Craftname = STUFF( Craftname, 13, 2, '04')
UPDATE inventarios SET  Craftname = STUFF( Craftname, 15, 2, '80') WHERE Craftname = STUFF( Craftname, 15, 2, '04')
UPDATE inventarios SET  Craftname = STUFF( Craftname, 17, 2, '80') WHERE Craftname = STUFF( Craftname, 17, 2, '04')
UPDATE inventarios SET  Craftname = STUFF( Craftname, 19, 2, '80') WHERE Craftname = STUFF( Craftname, 19, 2, '04')
```